# Can these posts be removed to open up this staircase railing?will I have to reinforce this beam? If so how would I do that?

Tags: walls, basement, structural, load-bearing, renovation

I noticed the showhome of our model had a basement renovated with an open staircase and I'm wondering how simple it would be to do this in our home. I've attached a photo of what it looks like in the showhome as well as what we have in our basement. Can someone please tell me if it's safe to remove a part of these posts as highlighted in my picture. Or if I would need to reinforce the beam?

Thank you![image][image]

Comment: While I agree strongly with Lee Sam's answer, I would strongly suggest you contact the builder, especially if they're still at the show home, and confirm with them. They're the ones who will know 100% without having to make any guesses or on-site inspections.

Answer (score 3):

We don’t know the span of the beam or the size of the beam or the actual load on the beam, but it appears that it was designed to have the opening in the wall because:

1. Single top plate.
2. Sole plate is not pressure treated indicating the entire wall was added later by a person not familiar with construction or knew it should be removed later. (The other sole plate in the picture is pressure treated, indicating that wall is to remain long term. )
3. The three posts on each end of the post do not sit on the sole plate, but rather extend through the floor (presumably to a support below). It appears there is just the top of a post base visible on the left post.

Neither triple stud posts have a post cap. I’d add one on each.

I’d also leave the double stud at the bottom of the stairs so you can turn the partial height wall horizontal and install a handrail.

If you give more info, like size of beam, span, etc. it could be determined that the beam is adequate or needs reinforcement.

Edit: Just to be clear, your question asks about removing “posts”. Those are “studs” you’ll be removing not posts. The triple studs at each end of the beam are posts, and they are to remain.

Comment: Also, and importantly, above the highlighted studs is what appears to be an LVL beam sitting on trippeled studs at each end. This is very likely to be carrying the load of the floor joists that abut the stair opening.

Comment: Note that there will need to be some sort of chase to enclose the wiring from the light switches (at the bottom of the stairs) that goes _around_ the header instead of through it (another indication that it's a carefully engineered load-carrying beam, not just some lumber thrown up there for fun).

Comment: I don't think as double top plate is needed when the wall is in-line line with a beam. not seeing any pressure treated wood. the end studs seems to have plastic boots instead.